# Double Defined Injected Module in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm pretty new to angular. I know that Angular supports DI but I have trouble of understanding why we need to define injected module($scope in this case) twice.

```
angular.module('docsBindExample', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Max Karl Ernst Ludwig Planck (April 23, 1858 – October 4, 1947)';
  }]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't *have* to define it twice for it to work as it is, but this is to save you from issues with minification.  When you minify, that `$scope` variable may be called something totally different, like `a`, and Angular won't know what that means -- it uses the strings to solve that issue.

I just ran that through a minifier to demonstrate:

```
angular.module("docsBindExample",[]).controller("Controller",["$scope",function(e){e.name="Max Karl Ernst Ludwig Planck (April 23, 1858 – October 4, 1947)"}])
```

This way, Angular can still match the dependencies up

Answer (score 1):

The strings are there to protect against minification/obfuscation. After that happens, your arguments/methods/variables etc. will get randomly renamed. That list of strings (in order) is one method to match the dependencies back up.